# rails active records returning wrong class type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i created a new model in rails with the following commands:

> rails g model prod_domain name:string type:string user_logon_name:string description:string email:string address:string company:string department:string dn:string sa_description:string is_sa:string sa_remap_description:string ownership:string comment:text

> rake db:migrate

i added some function in the model like this:

```
class ProdDomain < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.search_by_id(keyword)
    users = Array.new
      ProdDomain.where(id: keyword).find_each do |user|
      users.push(user)
    end
    return users
  end
  def self.search(keyword)
    users = []
    ProdDomain.where(dn: keyword).find_each do |user|
      users.push(user)
    end
    users
  end

end
```

however, when i try to find records in this model, i kept getting 'USER' class instead of 'ProdDomain' class, what am i doing wrong:

> (byebug) ProdDomain.find(1).class

> ProdDomain Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  `prod_domains`.* FROM `prod_domains` WHERE `prod_domains`.`id` = 1 LIMIT 1

> User(id: integer, email: string, encrypted_password: string, reset_password_token: string, reset_password_sent_at: datetime, remember_created_at: datetime, sign_in_count: integer, current_sign_in_at: datetime, last_sign_in_at: datetime, current_sign_in_ip: string, last_sign_in_ip: string, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, username: string, role: integer, dn: string, department: string, name: string)

Comment: Can you include your entire ProdDomain model and the migration generated by “rails g” ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a `type` column defined. In Rails the `type` column is used by default for indicating [inheritance](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html).
If you're not intending on using inheritance then you can rename the column (something like `kind` is common) or you can overwrite the column name that Rails will use `Base.inheritance_column`.

Comment: thanks, that was exactly the problem, it drove me crazy, i had "User" in the type field, make sense now